# How to make sure that the public key has not been tampered with during transit?

Tags: encryption, cryptography, public-key-infrastructure, man-in-the-middle

I understand how public key infrastructure works.

There is a private and public key, and someone may use the public key to encrypt data that can only be decrypted with the private key.

However there seems to be a flaw with this...

When you want someone, E.g Bob to send you a secret message, you send the key to him:
`Public key ==> Bob`

Bob then encrypts the data and sends it back to me.

`Data ==> Public key ==> back to me`

But what happens if at the first stage `Public key ==> Bob` an attacker modifies the public key to one he has the private key to, then decrypts the data Bob unknowingly sends?

How is this prevented?

Comment: Public key *cryptography* (PKC) uses public and private keys as you describe. Public key *infrastructure* (PKI) builds on this to distribute the public keys in a secure way which does NOT consist simply of 'Public key ==> Bob' exactly to prevent substitution or alteration. So apparently you don't understand PKI all that well. The brief answer is: usually a certificate signed by a CA or web-of-trust signed keys.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Either

- you give the public key to Bob when you physically meet him and mutually verify identities (as at a key-signing party), or
- Bob verifies your public key through a trusted introducer (e.g. a Certification Authority)

This is the "Infrastructure" part of PKI.

Comment: Makes sense, thanks. So there always has to be someone at the end of the day who you just *have* to trust (e.g CA)?

Comment: @JosephA. yes. Undertanding that such someone could be _yourself_

Comment: Option three, variation on option one, Bob *is* a CA and his certificate is already in your root trust store.

Comment: @Kevin Just wondering though, how is the transfer `CA --> Bob` protected against attackers?

Comment: @JosephA.: Either the CA is already trusted by Bob (because its public key is built into his operating system or browser; this is called a "root CA") or the CA presents its own certificate which is signed by another CA that Bob trusts.  Eventually everything chains back to a root CA.

Answer (score 1):

There are broadly two classes of methods: you deliver the public key in person (which assumes you yourself are immune from tampering in transit, of course), or you use a trustworthy intermediary to vouch for it, say, by signing a certificate — cryptographically or otherwise — or carrying it in a sealed and hopefully tamper-evident envelope.

In practice, private people interested in secure key exchange tend to come together and hold *keysigning parties*; there are well-established traditions for this sort of thing by now.  In cryptographic literature, the metaphor commonly used for secure key material delivery is *diplomatic pouch*.